# GFG problem error test case for python logic "Sort an array of 0s, 1s and 2s "

Tags: python, arrays, list

Given an array of size N containing only 0s, 1s, and 2s; sort the array in ascending order.

Example 1:

Input:
N = 5
arr[]= {0 2 1 2 0}
Output:
0 0 1 2 2
Explanation:
0s 1s and 2s are segregated
into ascending order.

INPUT CODE:
'''
class Solution:
def sort012(self,arr,n):
low = mid = arr[0]
high = len(arr)-1

```
    while mid <= high:
        if arr[mid] ==  0:
            arr[mid],arr[low] = arr[low],arr[mid]
            mid+=1
            low+=1
        elif arr[mid] == 1:
            mid+=1
        else:
            arr[mid],arr[high]= arr[high],arr[mid]
            high-=1
    return arr
    
    # code here
    # arr.sort()
    # return arr
```

'''

**ERROR TEST CASE**

Input:
65754
2 0 2 0 0 1 2 2 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 0 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 1 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 1 0 2 2 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 .................

Its Correct output is:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .................

And Your Code's output is:
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .................

Comment: Why so complicated? Just count the number of `0`, `1`, `2` and return array constructed with this information.

Comment: That's a nice approach thanks, brother...!!!

Answer (score 0):

why not use simply the built-in `sort()`?

`arr.sort()` should do the trick.

Is there a unique way you are trying to solve this ?

Comment: yeh I know that was built-in function but I wanna write the function to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def ZOT(arr):
    low = count = 0
    high = len(arr)-1 
    while(count<=high):
        
        # if arr[count] == 2 swap(arr[count],arr[high]) high--
        if arr[count] == 2:
            arr[count],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[count]
            high = high - 1
            
        # if arr[count] == 1 Dont swap anything, Increment count i.e, count++     
        elif arr[count] == 1:
            count = count +1
            
        # if arr[count] == 0 swap(arr[count],arr[low]) count++, low++   
        elif arr[count] == 0:
            arr[count],arr[low] = arr[low],arr[count]
            count = count + 1
            low = low + 1
            
        else:
            return -1
            
            
    return arr
if __name__=="__main__":
    arr = [0,1,2,1,2,0,2,0]
    print(ZOT(arr))

#Output : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).